# How to remove/replace/show unicode characters from NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, unicode

I'm parsing http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=48.209946,11.539421&output=csv. The response is 200,8,"Lerchenstraße 66, 80995 Munich, Germany". I'm only showing the CityName i.e., "Lerchenstraße 66". But the problem is that the CityName string has Unicode characters, and it is showing like "Lerchenstra\U00dfe66" in the view. The output should be like "Lerchenstrasse" or "Lerchenstraße".

```
-(void) httpDataDidFinishLoadingWithData:(NSData *)theData {
  m_activityLoaded=NO;
  temp=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[dataLoader httpData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSArray *listItems = [temp componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
  NSArray *tempCountryArray = [[listItems objectAtIndex:[listItems count]-3] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
  NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tempCountryArray];
  NSString *strTe=[[[[string
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""]
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""]
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"" ];
  self.cityNameString = strTe;
  NSLog(@"CITY NAME IS : %@", strTe);
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it is encoded, try to use `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:` and decode it.

Comment: Do you really mean "Lerchenstrabe" or is that a typo and you mean Lerchenstraße? (b vs. sharp s)

Comment: Also, it's the street name.

Comment: No problem then: "Munich" is ASCII only.

Comment: sorry , i want street name also... :D

Comment: You should post the parsing code.

Comment: You need to post some code. How do you get the data from the URL? How do you parse the data and put it into an NSString? You say it's showing incorrectly in the view, but don't say how you are displaying the text. Is it a UILabel? Is it in a webview?

Comment: I posted plz check it...

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer. Thanks for the support and suggestions. The code is:

```
NSString* esc1 = [strTe stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\u" withString:@"\\U"];
NSString* esc2 = [esc1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
NSString* quoted = [[@"\"" stringByAppendingString:esc2] stringByAppendingString:@"\""];
NSData* data = [quoted dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* unesc = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data
  mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NULL
  errorDescription:NULL];
assert([unesc isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]);
NSLog(@"Output = %@", unesc);
```

And the output is "Lerchenstraße66".

Comment: The google server sends an unescaped UTF8 string. It seems the `[dataLoader httpData]` (or `strTe`) is escaped in your app. So this fix just hides some erroneous processing of the incoming data.